# Unsure whether I need a group or a sort or something else

Tags: xslt-2.0

Hi I am an occasional user of XSLT so am probably missing something obvious, but hopefully someone can point it out!

The original XML has the structure;

```
<test>
   <input>a</input>
   <input>b</input>
   <input>c</input>
   <input>d</input>
   <input>e</input>
</test>
```

The XSL file contains the following processing commands;

```
<xsl:template name="convertInputToNumeric">
    <xsl:param name="inputs" />
        <xsl:for-each select="input">
            <NumericCode>
                <xsl:call-template name="toNumericCode">
                    <xsl:with-param name="type">Input</xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="" select="." />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </NumericCode>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

the call template 'toNumericCode' takes the current input and looks up in another xml file a numeric representation for the input eg the input 'a' returns the value '001'

```
 <Conversion type="Input">
    <Convert>
            <FROM>a</FROM>
            <TO>001</TO> 
        </Convert>
    <Convert>
                <FROM>b</FROM>
                <TO>002</TO>
        </Convert>
    <Convert>
                <FROM>c</FROM>
                <TO>001</TO>
        </Convert>
    <Convert>
                <FROM>d</FROM>
                <TO>001</TO>
    </Convert>
       <Convert>
                <FROM>e</FROM>
                <TO>002</TO>
    </Convert>
    </Conversion>
```

so running the XSL I currently get

```
<test>
   <NumericCode>001</NumericCode>
   <NumericCode>002</NumericCode>
   <NumericCode>001</NumericCode>
   <NumericCode>001</NumericCode>
   <NumericCode>002</NumericCode>
</test>
```

but actually what I want is that I only get the distinct  nodes eg

```
<test>
   <NumericCode>001</NumericCode>
   <NumericCode>002</NumericCode>
</test>
```

I don't know how best to do this as I would want to group based on the numeric code value that is returned from the template 'toNumericCode' rather than the initial input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use distinct-values(). Have look, I have change your shared template with this one:

```
<xsl:template name="convertInputToNumeric">
  <xsl:param name="inputs" />
  <xsl:parm name="abc"><xsl:for-each select="input">
    <NumericCode>
      <xsl:call-template name="toNumericCode">
        <xsl:with-param name="type">Input</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </NumericCode>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:parm>
  <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($abc/NumericCode)">
    <NumericCode><xsl:value-of select="."/></NumericCode>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

output:

```
<NumericCode>001</NumericCode><NumericCode>002</NumericCode>
```

Comment: Thanks! That to me is pure witchcraft.  I tried previously to assign it to a variable in order to do something similar, but the processor just complained and it didn't occur to me to try a param. I can't profess to understand why your solution works with a param.